# how to display JavaScript alert only on mobile screen

Tags: javascript

I want to show a JavaScript alert only on mobile devices.

because my website is not responsive on mobile so I want to alert users to visit on desktop.

Comment: Check out this: https://abdessalam.dev/blog/detect-device-type-javascript/

Comment: [Detect if the device is a mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381673/detecting-a-mobile-browser) then either display a certain page or alert

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

use The read-only Window property **innerWidth** to detect the viewport size then you can be fancy with your code or can keep it simple like the follwing,

```
// create a function that will be called based on the size of a specific viewport
function reportWindowSize() {        
    //check if the viweport size is less then 1200px
    if (window.innerWidth < 1200) { 
        // Ignore the following two lines of code; they were written for 
        // testing on DOM; you can even use this one if you want to.
        // const body = document.querySelector("body");
           body.innerHTML = "Please go to my desktop site to see the awesome 
           content.";    

        // your code
        // notify the user to visit the desktop site with an alert()
        alert("Please go to my desktop site to see the awesome content.");
    };
    
 // Add a Window: resize event to the Window interface to force a reload of the 
 // page if the viewport size is greater than or equal to 1200px.

    window.addEventListener("resize" , () => {
     // check if viewport width is greater than or equal to 1200px.
        if (window.innerWidth >= 1200) {
         // reload/refresh the page
            location.reload();
        };
    });
};

// call your function when page loads 
   window.onload = reportWindowSize;
// call your function when viewport resize
   window.onresize = reportWindowSize;
```